# Migrating multiple courses from one server to another moodle server all at once

Tags: linux, moodle, moodle-api

We are trying to migrate some courses (100+ courses) from one moodle server to another Linux moodle server.
We tried to backup and restore individual courses but it is time-consuming. Is there any other way available, to backup all courses and restore them all at once?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command line to back up and restore courses, so you could run a batch

```
php admin/cli/backup.php --courseid=2 --destination=/mybackup/

php admin/cli/restore_backup.php --file=/mybackup/filexyz.mbz --categoryid=1
```

https://docs.moodle.org/310/en/Course_backup#Backup_via_CLI_for_administrators

https://docs.moodle.org/400/en/Course_restore#Restore_via_CLI_for_administrators